# В чем различие curl и requests python?

Tags: python, curl, requests, soap

Дано:

1. API, которое понимает SOAP запросы
2. Один запрос в формате xml

Что делаем:

Отправляем запросы к данному API двумя различными способами, через `curl` и с помощью модуля `requests` от python.

Что имеем в итоге:

`curl` отрабатывает замечательно, возвращает 200 ответ, все супер. `requests.post` от python'a ни в какую не собирается мне показывать то, что я желаю. Ответ от сервера 400 и иди гуляй.

Что было сделано:

1. Переправерены содержания `headers` и `body` (совпадают с содержанием при `curl`-запросе, за исключением `User-Agent`)
2. Подмена `User-Agent` на версию `curl` и другие варианты
3. Проверены кодировки (`utf-8`)
4. При запросе используется один и тот же файл `.xml`, чтобы избежать лексической ошибки или разногласий.

На SO популярный запрос такого плана `curl vs requests`, но все они так или иначе исправляют ошибки, которые я перепроверил (кодировка, заголовки и проч.) и направляют на ресурсы, которые переделывают `curl  в python` - запросы. Что не решает мою проблему=(

Итак, лог от `requests` (хосты, пользователя и токен заблюрил):

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.***********.com:443
send: b'POST /soap/v013/ HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: curl/7.55.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8\r\nSOAPAction: "**************/soap/invoiceList"\r\nHost: ***************.com\r\nContent-Length: 349\r\n\r\n'
send: b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header><customer>******</customer><token>**************</token></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><invoiceListRequest/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n'
header: Date: Wed, 05 May 2021 10:37:22 GMT
header: Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
header: Content-Length: 319
header: Connection: close
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://www.**********.com:443 "POST /soap/v013/ HTTP/1.1" 400 319
<Response [400]>
```

Есть мысли почему так получается?

**UPD**: по просьбам из комментариев сам запрос:

```
main_soap_action = "**********"
HOST = "https://www***********/soap/v013/"

def mk_headers(action):
    soap = main_soap_action + action 
    headers = {"Content-Type":"text/xml;charset=utf-8",
    "SOAPAction":soap,
    "Host":"**********.com",
    "User-Agent":"curl/7.55.1",
    }
    return headers

headers = mk_headers("invoiceList")
payload = "testrq.xml"
with open(payload) as p:
     response = requests.post(url=HOST, headers=headers, data= p.read().replace("\n",""))
```

Значение для `User-Agent` не обязательное, я просто тестил)

**UPD2** По совету в коментариях пустил запросы на локальный сервер для сравнения:

от `curl` (который дает 200 ответ)

```
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: */*
'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8'
'SOAPAction: https://www.********/invoiceList'
'Host: ********.com'
Content-Length: 373
```

от `python-requests`

```
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept-encoding: *
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: https://www.*********/invoiceList
Host: **********.com
Content-Length: 373
```

По `Content-Length: 373` можно понять что содержание совершенно одинаковое, поэтому не включаю. Что ж различия видны, хотя бы в наличии двух значений `Host` в верном запросе, значения `Accept-encoding: *` и наличия кавычек в верном варианте

Comment: покажите код запроса с requests?

Comment: а если в User-Agent что-то такое: "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36" и в requests вместо data= указать file=?

Comment: @Jack_oS да, именно это я и пробовал, когда писал про различные варианты. Решил остановиться на версии `curl` потому что этот заголовок гарантировано валиден

Comment: Запустите локально netcat (`nc -k -l 10000`) и выполните запросы к нему (т.е. замените хост и порт в запросах на `localhost:10000`), чтобы увидеть полностью http запросы в двух случаях. Это самый простой и быстрый способ увидеть в чем разница.

Comment: То что длина одинаковая, не означает, что содержимое одинаковое. Нужно проверить посимвольно. Вполне возможно, что содержимое неправильно перекодировалось.

Comment: В кавычки в заголовках - это очень странно. Это синтаксически неверный HTTP запрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, что ж, светлая голова по утру дает результаты. Вопрос решен.

Что сделано (только логика):

По итогу я психанул и написал функцию, которая перебирает все возможные `headers` и отправляет запросы к API. Я отталкивался от того, что содержание `body` верно. Да, это не очень корректно по отношению к разработчикам API, но по итогу я не сделал больше 30 запросов за 5 сек. Т.е. я перебрал все `Content-Type` и `User-Agent` в том числе и их отсутствие.

Результат:

После запуска скрипта я был удивлен, что единственный запрос, который отдал ожидаемый результат оказался запросом в котором `headers` не включены совсем. Т.е. сработал вот этот запрос:

```py
response = requests.post(url=HOST, data= body)
```

Полного понимания так и нет, почему `curl` с заголовками срабатывает, а `requests` срабатывает без них. Это уже вопрос на подумать на выходных.

Итог:

Отсутствие документации для SOAP API все-таки минус. Разработчики, которые тебе отдают `wsdl` и говорят, что там все есть и другой документации не предусмотрено, все таки лукавят. Каждый раз подбирать запросы и работать с такими сервисами хочется все меньше.

Comment: все же, в requests по-умолчанию есть `user-agent` в заголовке, что-то такое: `python-requests`

Comment: @Jack_oS естественно заголовки будут включены автоматически. Проверил на ответе там вот это вот: `{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.25.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '373'}`